# Custom Cursor built using Web Animations API doesn't use the correct "easing" and "duration"

Tags: javascript, custom-cursor, web-animations-api

I am trying to build a custom cursor **specifically** using the Web Animations API in JavaScript. I've tried using both the `mousemove` event and `requestAnimationFrame()` to make this work. However, the cursor never follows the specified `duration` and `easing`.

While the two settings work with a single animation, however, when invoking multiple `animate()` promises, it shows the aforementioned problem.

I also read that the browser "automatically removes filling animation" as mentioned in the [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Animation#automatically_removing_filling_animations) in case that was the problem.

Here's the code snippet.

```js
const CURSOR = document.querySelector("#cursor");

window.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
  const animation = CURSOR.animate([{
    transform: `translate3d(${e.clientX}px, ${e.clientY}px, 0) translate(-50%, -50%)`
  }], {
    duration: 4000,
    easing: "linear"
  });

  animation.onfinish = () => {
    animation.commitStyles();
  }
});
```

```css
#cursor {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: black;
  will-change: transform;
}
```

```html
<div id="cursor"></div>
```

I've also tested this with different `css` properties instead of `transform`. Like `top` `left`, `margin-top` `margin-left`.

Comment: *Why* are you **specifically** doing this with the Web Animations API? Have you considered using transitions instead?

Comment: I'm writing an article on "different ways to build a custom cursor". I have built it with `CSS` Only, `CSS` + JS `mousemove` event, and `CSS` + JS `requestAnimationFrame`. This is the fourth method.